Замыкания. Логика Функции заключается в добавлении в файл всех данных в том же виде
Подскажите пожалуйста, логика задачи записывать в файл данные любого типа, т.е. в добавлении в файл file_name всех данных из data_set в том же виде.
Мое решение просто печатает строку data, file но никак не записывает их в файл
def get_advanced_writer(file_name):
     def write_everything(*data_set):
         with open (file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
             for data in data_set:
                 print(data, file)
     return write_everything
    
 write = get_advanced_writer('example.txt')
 write('Это строчка', ['А', 'это', 'уже', 'число', 5, 'в', 'списке'])


«в том же виде» и «любого типа» — вещи взаимоисключающие

Ну а в том коде, который вы показали, сильно напрашивается заменить print(data, file) на print(data, file=file)
